# extracting a data from an arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

**i have this sample list from a file**

```
firstname, lastname, age
anne, smith, 6
dougie, miller, 8
```

right now i am stuck with the arraylist

```
ArrayList<String[]> rows = new ArrayList<>();
     while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] row = line.split(",");
        rows.add(row);
    }

    for (String[] row : rows) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
    }
```

and i got these output:

```
[firstname,lastname,age]
[anne,smith,6]
[dougie,miller,8]
```

i have tried using doing this:

```
String[] x1 = new String[rows.size()+1];
     for(int i=0;i<rows.size();i++){
     String[] lastname = (String[]) rows.get(i+1);
        System.out.println(lastname[1]);
        //x1[i]=lastname[1];
     }
```

but i couldn't seem to put the lastname in one array. it will give me this error:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 227, Size: 227

i want to have this output:

```
firstname
anne
dougie

lastname
smith
miller

age
6
8
```

how do i do that?

Comment: You say you don't get output, but you show us the output you have. You also talk about `ArrayList`, but there is none in your code. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: You want arraylist or file read and output? Or you want file read and initialize arraylist from the file?

Comment: Where's the `ArrayList`? I'm searching for that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one should work fine, provided the StringArrays are all same sized:

```
int cols = rows.size() > 0 ? rows.get(0).length : 0;
for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < rows.size(); j++) {
    System.out.println(rows.get(j)[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought about using a simpler solution, using `Scanner`:

```
File file = new File(filePath);
try {
    Scanner content = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\n");
    while (content.hasNext()) {
        String[] line = content.next().split(",\\s");
        for (String s : line) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```